Python Pyspark dataframe Object to R sparklyr dataframe object, is the conversion possible?
I want to execute python in R, I found reticulate, it is R package to execute python code. However, the python code returns a pyspark dataframe object, how can I convert it to an R object (potentially sparklyr dataframe) then to data.table in R?
let's assume this is the code that generates a pyspark dataframe object that could be executed using reticulate:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('random_dataframe').getOrCreate()
schema = ["id", "value"]

df = spark.range(0, 100).select("id", (rand(seed=42) * 100).alias("value"))

in R, I am doing the basics of reticulate package:
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python")
py_run_string("<PYTHON CODE AS ONE LINE STRING>")

After that using py_to_r() to convert the python df to un R object gives an error (ERROR: Unwanted conversion type), if I understood correctly, there isn't an implementation in reticulate package to convert pyspark dataframe to an R object.
Question
is there a solution for that? and is there a solution that invloves pyarrow instead of pyspark, for instance, if the python code returns pyarrow table, can I convert it to R object?

NOTE: reticulate has no problem converting pandas to data.table object in R, but Converting the pyspark dataframe to pandas then to data.table is not possible since it crashes machine which has 49GB RAM (I am dealing with big data)

really appreciate any help!

Since arrow is using parquet files it should be possible to save your data with pyarrow and load it into R with the {arrow} package.

I thought about that, but it will be annoying to save a file for every data I retrieve (I will end up with 15 files to reload them in R), but if it is the only option, I won't complain haha, Thanks a lot man for your suggestion

If you are on Databricks then you could create a temporary view (DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView), and read as a Spark table in R.
